# Linux output line numbers where string match appears

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

what I'm looking to do is boost the command I already have to return line numbers of where the specified string appears:

```
grep -r -l -n -w "ePKI" /home/websites/www/* > /home/keywords.txt
```

The command above returns filenames like

```
filename_where_keyword_appears_01.txt
filename_where_keyword_appears_02.txt
etc
```

And what I would like it to do is return the line number of where the string appears in file too, like:

```
filename_where_keyword_appears_01.txt 12 45 67 89
```

Could anyone possibly advise me on improving my command to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You might get similar results to what you want by omitting -l and using cut as follows:

```
grep -r -n -w "ePKI" /home/websites/www/*|cut -d':' -f 1,2 > /home/keywords.txt
```

If you need the output to be exactly as you described, you could try with awk:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1 {printf "\n%s",FILENAME};/ePKI/ {printf " %d ",NR} END {printf "\n"}' /home/websites/www/*
```

Combine it with find for recursion:

```
find /home/websites/www/* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 awk -F, 'FNR==1 {printf "\n%s",FILENAME};/ePKI/ {printf " %d ",NR} END {printf "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Option `-l` suppresses normal output and prints only the file name. Omit option `-l` and keep option `-n` to see the file name *and* the line numbers. Additionally you will see the matching line, or only the matching part when specifying option `-o`.